# Converting server time to any given local time in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, utc, timezone-offset

This is the code im running in my server side nodejs for conversion.

```
convertNowToTimezone = (localOffset) => {
  let d = new Date();
  let millis = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000); //convert server local time to UTC millisec
  d.setTime(millis - (localOffset * 60000)); //convert UTC millisec to required local time
  return d;
}
```

localOffset is -330 (IST offset), this gives a diff of 4min.

How to get this thing right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `moment` to work with dates in javascript.

You can easily manage timezones with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

```js
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

moment().tz("UTC").format();
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

```js
console.log(moment().tz("UTC").format());
console.log(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

> localOffset is -330 (IST offset), this gives a diff of 4min.

Check that your server time is synchronized. You can use [ntp](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html) for that if you're using a linux server.

Comment: I came across this, but I don't want to add a dependency for one single utility function.

Comment: If your issue is the 4 min difference, the problem like I said is that your server time is not synchronized, which you won't need to add `momentjs`. `momentjs` was my recommendation for handling dates in javascript.

Answer (score -1):

JS straight up:

```
const dateISOString = '2019-10-03T02:45:02'; // UTC server time or --> new Date()
const aest = new Date(new Date(dateISOString).toLocaleString('en-AU', { timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney' }));
console.log("aest.toISOString(): " + aest.toISOString());
```